# CakePHP encoding html entities

Tags: html, cakephp, url-encoding

Greetings,

I'm having a strange issue with data sent to Cake via URL path. If the path includes url encoded entities, the encoded chars appear to get stripped off and the rest of the URL path is not getting passed to my controller. For example:

`http://mydomain.com/products/search/pants+%26%2A%25+shoes/1/pg-2/`

This should pass the string `pants &*% shoes` to my products controller's `search()` action as the first argument, with `1` and `pg-2` as the other two args. But instead I just get `pants` (with trailing space) as the first arg and no second or third arg. I have made sure the Sanitize class is not being used and I have `Configure::write('App.encoding', 'UTF-8');` set.

Any thoughts?

Thanks bunches,

-saturn

**Update:** Cake is seeing %26 as an ampersand separator of query string arguments. Shouldn't Cake know the difference between a query string separator and a literal char? Or am I missing something bleeding obvious? (I have been working a lot of hours...)

**Update 2:** I think this may be a bug. If I pass a URL like:

`http://mydomain.com/products/search/?q=pants%20%2A%24%25%5E%26%20shoes&cat=1&pg=2`

Cake parses it correctly, that is, the various args are stored as query string params in `$this->params['url']`. The hiccup appears to be only when using an encoded ampersand in the URL path.

By the way, I'm using the latest Cake 1.3.6.

I'm very interested to know anyone else's opinion on this. Thanks.

Comment: I can confirm that the URL is cut off after the first ampersand. It's possibly best to file a ticket for this.